# c# Selenium does not follow links in a loop

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to iterate through all the links on the page. Go to each one and display the information on the link page. On the first iteration of the loop, the program works correctly. But on the second line `item.GetAttribute("href")` gives an error. Although item is definitely a link. In the code example, I removed the loop and repeated the same code twice. And still the error appears

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.Url = @"https://forrest-med.ru/#services";

  var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'service/')]"));
  await Task.Delay(1000);

  var ar = elements.ToArray();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//  for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
//  {


      string href = "";
      var item = ar[1]; //The link is the same

      try
      {
          href = item.GetAttribute("href"); //First time. 
    //Everything is Ok
      }
      catch
      {
      //    continue;
      }

      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(href);

      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

      try
      {
          var el = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("service-title"));
          sb.Append(el.Text + "\n"); ;
      }
      catch
      {
        //  continue;
      }

      driver.Navigate().Back();

      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
 
  ////////
 
  href = "";
  item = ar[1];//The link is the same

  try
  {
      href = item.GetAttribute("href"); //Second time. Error
  }
  catch
  {
      //    continue;
  }

  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(href);

  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
  try
  {
      var el = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("service-title"));
      sb.Append(el.Text + "\n"); ;
  }
  catch
  {
      //  continue;
  }

  driver.Navigate().Back();

  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
  // }

  parsingText.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice, if you give us details about the error you're seeing for the second link.

But, I'm almost sure, the problem is that you're trying to keep an array of the elements from the page the isn't exist anymore. Every element is just an interface (some handy to use gateway) to the actual DOM element in the browser, so once you navigate to the second page, all the elements from the previous one gets destroyed. You still have those `IWebElement` instances on your array, but they're pointing to nowhere.

As far as I can see, you're only use `href` from those links, so why not to store just those URLs you need to navigate?

Here's your code (if I grasp everything correctly) that works just fine:

```cs
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

driver.Url = "https://forrest-med.ru/#services";

var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'service/')]"));
var serviceUrls = elements.Select(e => e.GetAttribute("href")).ToList();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var url in serviceUrls)
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    if (driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("service-title")) is { } el)
    {
        string title = el.Text;
        sb.AppendLine(title);
    }
}

parsingText.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made an array of links and everything worked